# How to use string.format with string array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-formatting

I want to output a formated string to console. I have one string variable and one string array variable.

When I do this:

```
$arr = "aaa","bbb"
"test {0} + {1}" -f "first",$arr
```

The output is this:

```
test first + System.Object[]
```

But I need output to be:

```
test first + aaa,bbb
```

Or something similar...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Several options:

1. Join the array first, so you don't rely on the default `ToString()` implementation (which just prints the class name):

   ```
   PS> 'test {0} + {1}' -f 'first',($arr -join ',')
   test first + aaa,bbb
   ```
2. Use string interpolation:

   ```
   PS> $first = 'first'
   PS> "test $first + $arr"
   test first + aaa bbb
   ```

   You can change the delimiter used by setting `$OFS`, which by default is a space:

   ```
   PS> $OFS = ','
   PS> "test $first + $arr"
   test first + aaa,bbb
   ```
3. You can get the same result (including the note about `$OFS`) with

   ```
   PS> 'test {0} + {1}' -f 'first',(''+$arr)
   test first + aaa bbb
   ```

   This forces the array to be converted into a single string first, too.

Comment: Very nice! I would normally use string interpolation right away, but I just discovered -f operator for string.format and liked it so much I used it everywhere and got confused :)   This raises another question what is the difference in background processing of -f operator and string interpolation? Maybe some articles? Thanks

Comment: `-f` is just a straightforward convenience for `String.Format()`, it uses the same semantics as .NET in that regard. String interpolation is a tricky subject, as it converts objects to string using the invariant culture (apparently); it will also join arrays using `$OFS`. Generally I don't feel confident right now to accurately summarise the exact differences. Something fun: `$a = (date),(date),(date); Write-Host $a; Write-Host "$a"`